# NullPointerException with android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: java, android

I am currently trying to implement a navigation drawer in my app. I am having an issue with the Toolbar being null. I have done many searches online and tried many different solutions to no avail.  I have not finished writing all the code but I can't launch my app to check the navigation drawer. Can anyone see where I went wrong?

If there is anything else I need to post, let me know.

I included this on all my activity screens

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    layout="@layout/app_bar"/>
```

app_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
   android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
   app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" >
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

line 72 of MainActivity

```
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

Main Activity

```
public class Trans_List extends ActionBarActivity {
  private Toolbar mToolbar;
  private CharSequence mTitle;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_trans_list);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        NavigationDrawerFragment drawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.left_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp((DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
```

Style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.split" parent="AppBaseTheme">

    </style>

    <style name="dialog_custom" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
        <item name="@android:listPreferredItemPaddingLeft">20dip</item>
        <item name="@android:listPreferredItemPaddingRight">20dip</item>
        <item name="@android:listPreferredItemPaddingStart">20dip</item>
        <item name="@android:listPreferredItemPaddingEnd">20dip</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

LogCat

```
01-07 01:14:29.702    4811-4811/com.lee.yuchan.splt E/AndroidRuntime﹕
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.lee.yuchan.splt, PID: 4811
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lee.yuchan.splt/com.lee.yuchan.splt.Trans_List}:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
'java.lang.CharSequence android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.getTitle()'
on a null object reference
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.getTitle()' on a null object
reference
                at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:95)
                at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:88)
                at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar.<init>(ToolbarActionBar.java:84)
                at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setSupportActionBar(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:175)
                at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setSupportActionBar(ActionBarActivity.java:92)
                at com.lee.yuchan.splt.Trans_List.onCreate(Trans_List.java:72)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Main Activity XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!-- The main content view -->
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/selectItems"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/select_instr1"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="4sp"
            android:paddingBottom="10sp" >
        </TextView>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </ListView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonChecked"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dip"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="@string/next_button" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_dr"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.lee.yuchan.splt.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue with the toolbar. I realized after hours of searching the web and trying different things, I realized that my code wasn't wrong, it was using layouts from the layout-21 not the layout folder since the emulation for Android 5.0. All modification I had made were in the layout folder. I made the changes to the xml files in the layout-21 folder and the problem was solved. Sorry for the wasted time and post.

Comment: Since you are using the appcompat-stuff you don't have to separate/duplicate layouts between api 21 and below, at least not for the toolbar and related stuff like toolbar-styles. You know that, right?

Answer (score 17):

Set the `id` attribute in the `Toolbar` xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" >
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Then remove it from the `include` block so it looks like this:

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar"/>
```

And to simplify further you could just remove the `include` block completely and simply insert the `Toolbar` directly into the xml where the `include` was.

Comment: I tried but it still doesn't work. What do you mean by inserting the Toolbar directly?

Comment: @jonlee83 please edit your question and add the entire `xml` for the layout of the crashing activity

Comment: I added the main activity's xml. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

```
<include
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
layout="@layout/tool_bar"/>
```

android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.getTitle() on a null object reference happens due to title clashes between ids of  and that of the id in toolbar.xml definition . To overcome this issue remove the id in  as below and latest Lollipop material design shall work fine with toolbar

```
<include
layout="@layout/tool_bar"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

When I had this problem, I configured the layout of the activity and of the toolbar with the same id's

Answer (score 3):

i was struck with the same issue and none of the answer's worked for me, i had actually forgotten to include the toolbar layout in the activity.

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

In my own case, i had used

```
@Bind(R.id.toolbar)
protected Toolbar toolbar;
```

at the top of my code but forgot to do

```
ButterKnife.bind(this);
```

inside `onCreate()` method

I hope that helps someone

Remember to add

```
 compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
```

to your `build.gradle` dependencies and import

```
import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
```

in your java code and rebuild your app.

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue with Toolbar that wasn't of `support.v7`
I mean that you must add `android.support.v7.widget.` before the cast you realize when finding `Toolbar` with ID...

Answer (score 0):

In my case , i was trying to access the `Toolbar` inside `onAttach()` method of a fragment instead of `onActivityCreated()` , resulting in `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is a little late but I just ran into this problem.

I had a similar issue and spent 7 hrs messing with it.  It worked on 3 of 4 activities just fine but one would crash.

The only thing that worked for me, and I am not sure why, was to put the:

```
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

as the last code in my onCreate.  It works perfectly now.

Comment: It may be that you had these 3 lines of code before calling the setContentView() for the Activity layout

Answer (score 0):

check both line  call is ok or not

```
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_file)
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_top)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause is using a wrong layout in `setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout)`

Answer (score 0):

I read another time your code...and I saw that you haven't defined the ID of your toolbar in your `MainActivity XML`...see your include in it :

```xml
<include layout="@layout/app_bar" />

<!-- But where's ID attribute here ? -->

<!-- add android:id="@+id/app_bar" -->

<!-- to finally have below : -->

<include layout="@layout/app_bar" android:id="@+id/app_bar" />
```

After that...you won't get this error 'cause your toolbar is finally found and isn't set to '`null`'.