# Android xml rendering issue in eclipse?

Tags: android, android-layout

On creating new xml files in a project, rendering issue occur with error log as follows:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
    The following classes could not be instantiated:
    - android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar (Open Class, Show Error Log)
    - android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView (Open Class, Show Error Log)
    - android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar (Open Class, Show Error Log)

...............

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.getDecorToolbar(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:594)
    at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.pullChildren(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:583)
    at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:368)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:875)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.measureView(RenderSessionImpl.java:637)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:537)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:323)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:349)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:519)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1584)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1309)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.activated(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1066)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.delegateActivated(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:743)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonXmlEditor.activated(CommonXmlEditor.java:416)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.LayoutWindowCoordinator.partActivated(LayoutWindowCoordinator.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartService$6.run(PartService.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartService.partActivated(PartService.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$17.run(WorkbenchPage.java:4870)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.firePartActivated(WorkbenchPage.java:4867)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$18(WorkbenchPage.java:4846)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$E4PartListener.partActivated(WorkbenchPage.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$3.run(PartServiceImpl.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.firePartActivated(PartServiceImpl.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:692)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.hidePart(PartServiceImpl.java:1276)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.hidePart(PartServiceImpl.java:1215)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.closePart(StackRenderer.java:1218)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.access$3(StackRenderer.java:1200)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer$12.close(StackRenderer.java:1092)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1874)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

Comment: Look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810184/nullpointerexception-with-android-support-v7-widget-toolbar

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I restarted my eclipse. Its working fine now.
The problem is sdk is not loaded properly in my eclipse.

Try to start eclipse otherwise once check your sdk manager is everything installed or not.

Answer (score 6):

I have met the same problem When using Eclipse with ADT (both are the latest version).

It seems like a bug of adt, the only solution I found (but a simple one) is just restart Eclipse, then the errors disappear.

Comment: It occurs when I try to create a new android application project in Eclipse.

Comment: did you solve this issue? I am also getting same problem what is solution for it.

Answer (score 3):

Google has been deprecated the Class `ActionBarActivity`.If your 'Activity Class' `extends` it, this error occurs.

1. First Change the `ActionBarActivity`to `Activity` and save Changes.
2. Then, restart your IDE and see error is fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Have you used any fragment in your xml? please add the library supported for fragmnet named "android-support-v7-appcompat"

Comment: No i am not using any fragment in xml. same problem for every xml.

Answer (score 0):

I Was Getting The Same Error !!

But What I have Learned Is when I go Below API 14 i gt the Error Otherwise It works Fine ....

The issue was fixed in an update to 4.1 SDK, but the fix has not been backported to older versions of the layout library -- yet. I believe Xav is planning on doing that along with a few other misc layoutlib fixes that have accumulated.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same error and have solved this.

I've created a new project and selected API 21. After the project was created I changed in the file `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
android:targetSdkVersion="21"
```

to

```
android:targetSdkVersion="22"
```

Answer (score 0):

I start my eclipse again it works fine now. Also in some cases it might occur on creating a new activity, in that case you need to remove some access generated code in AndroidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the AndroidManifest.xml:

`android:targetSdkVersion="21"` to `android:targetSdkVersion="22"`

Then change ActionBarActivity to Activity.