# Android XML layout NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

java.lang.NullPointerException Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log

The following classes could not be instantiated:

```
- android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar (Open Class, Show Error Log) 
- android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView (Open Class, Show Error Log) 
- android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar (Open Class, Show Error Log)
```

See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.

Comment: please can you add your xml file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android xml rendering issue in eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29360486/android-xml-rendering-issue-in-eclipse)

Comment: post your complete log cat..

Answer (score 0):

Go to `File > Invalidate Caches/Restart`.  This should help your IDE restore the cache since this is just an issue with the renderer. Worked for me for the same exception.