# My recyclerview is overlapping my toolbar. How to fix?

Tags: android, xml, android-toolbar

I am using AppCompatActivity so I am using a toolbar.

Basically, I want the toolbar to be fixed and everything to come below the toolbar - but this is proving troublesome.

This is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar_custom"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/carRecycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="375dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Even when I try manually moving the recyclerview underneath the toolbar - the app crashes!

Would mean a lot if someone could help me out

EDIT: 
So my app is crashing here:

```
public class ViewCars extends AppCompatActivity {
     private ToolBar toolbar;
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_bar);
            // CRASHES ON THIS LINE!!!
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            setContentView(R.layout.carspage);
        }
}
```

This is the error trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{benj.samplesapp/benj.samplesapp.ViewCars}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                          at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:100)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:93)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar.<init>(ToolbarActionBar.java:78)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:204)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:99)
                                                                          at benj.samplesapp/benj.samplesapp.ViewCars.onCreate(ViewCars.java:6)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

try to set the marginTop of the recyclerView

android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include
    layout="@layout/toolbar_custom"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/carRecycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="375dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Update :**

you are trying to get reference before setting it. put your setContentView after calling supper. check bellow

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.carspage);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}
```

Comment: put your error log in your question plus the codes your are crashing

Comment: Sure, its in the edited post above. Thing is, it was working before, but not when I move the recyclerview below the bar. I am starting to hate this already lol

Comment: still same crash log generated?

Comment: don't give up. are u using any other layout folder like layout-21? check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/a/27831587/1263362

Comment: Hi, no I am not using any other layout folder such as layout-21. As in it was working before and it works now if the toolbar is being overlapped by the recyclerview

Comment: if u are using git then add it to it & give me the link. I will check in free time

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I don't use git. I am new to large-scale programming

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107465/discussion-between-sayem-and-benj-mikesozery).

Answer (score 0):

Any thing you put below a layout will overlap it, so try putting the recyclerview above the toolbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/carRecycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="375dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
<include
layout="@layout/toolbar_custom"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -3):

Use the attribute below="yourtoolbar" in the xml inside the recyclerview

Comment: edit your answer with explanation for better understand of others.